# JavaScript "Image.onload" fires even if the image is not found

Tags: javascript, image, promise

I am trying to load some image for a HTML canvas game. And I want them to load before I start the game. So I created a function to load them synchronously before my game starts. But the problem is,

**if the image does not exists, it still fires "Image.onload()"**.

I want to return an object with "error=true" if the image doesn't exist.
But couldn't find a way.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function loadImages(images) {
    return {
        list: images,
        loaded: {},
        failed: {},
        _load(src, name){
            return new Promise((resolve)=>{
                let image = new Image()
                image.onload = resolve({ name, src, image, error: false })
                image.onerror = resolve({ name, src, image: null, error: true })
                image.src = src
            })
        }
    }
}

let myLoader = loadImages("some image list")
let image = await myLoader._load("https://someUrl.com/img.png", "imageName")

console.log(image)
```

if you look at the console you'll see the "onload" gets fired not "onerror".

Comment: What HTTP Status Code is being returned for your not found images? If an error page is coming back as 200, then JavaScript may still think it has been successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` and `onerror` should be set to a function, instead you're calling a function and assigning the return to them.

```
image.onload = e => resolve({ name, src, image, error: false })
image.onerror = e => resolve({ name, src, image: null, error: true })
```